# Nearby Connections API: Android 5 won't detect Android 11 advertising

Tags: android, google-nearby, google-nearby-connections

I have 2 device (Android 5 and 11) and I tried testing them in each other.

The Android 11 device detects advertising of Android 5 but, it doesn't detect if Android 11 is the advertiser and Android 5 is the browser. It just don't detect.

P.S: I have setted the permission and granted but the Android 11's advertising, still won't detect.

Answer (score 0):

I have this problem too, an Android 11 device that can discover others but cannot be discovered by other devices.

Comment: Better a comment rather than an answer.

Comment: Well I solved the problem. In my case the location wasn't turned on for the device that was discovering. Maybe it is the same for you.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32656170)